# In Acumatica, using @me inside Relations Section of Generic Inquiry

Tags: acumatica

We want to have a sales order dashboard where we only show orders for certain sales people based on the logged in user.  For example, we have sales people BB and CR who share an assistant TP.  BB can see his orders on the dashboard.  CR can see his orders on the dashboard.  TP can see orders for both of them on his dashboard.  We also have people outside of sales who need to see all orders.  We want to do all of this without having to create a bunch of custom dashboards.  We wanted to maintain 2 dashboards - one filtered one for sales people and one unfiltered one for everyone else.

We have gotten close to solution by using a generic inquiry.  We created custom fields on the salesperson that point back to a logged in user (UserID1 and UserID2).  Multiple custom fields were used because a single sales person could be visible to 2 people.  We then joined SOOrder to SalesPerson inside our GI.  We then wanted to join the Users table on (SalesPerson.UserID1 = Users.PKID AND SalesPerson.UserID1 = @me) OR (SalesPerson.UserID2 = Users.PKID AND SalesPerson.UserID2 = @me).  That would allow us to create a filter where Users.PKID is not null to limit the view for sales people and then not use any filter on the non-sales dashboard.

The problem is that @me is not available on the Relations section.  It is only available on the conditions section.  We tried to just have the join of SalesPerson.UserID1 = Users.PKID or SalesPerson.UserID2 = Users.PKID and then creating the condition for the @me portion.  The issue there is that it only shows records with a match.  That won't work for non-sales people.

Is there some way to include @me or an equivalent on the relations tab?  Any better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Built-in variables like '@me' aren't well documented which raises questions about support of this feature.

Try this instead:

1. In generic inquiry TABLES tab, add table 'PX.Data.AccessInfo'.
2. In PARAMETERS tab, add a new parameter (ex: 'P1') and set the Schema Field value to 'Accessinfo.UserID' (use 'Accessinfo' or the alias for that table declared in TABLES tab).
3. In the RELATIONS tab in the join condition Child Field you can reference the '[P1]' variable.
4. Accessinfo DAC contains current record of the logged in user and reflects the information you see when you click your profile in the top right of Acumatica pages. If the solution doesn't work right away you can debug it with the Request Profiler page to look up the generated SQL query for the GI.